# UIView with many TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have ViewController_1 with Button_1:

```
@interface ViewController_1 : UIViewController  <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{ 
  IBOutlet UIView *secondView;
  UITableView *myTable;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

All tableView delegate methods are implemented in ViewController_1.m

In ViewController_1.xib I have 2 views (View of ViewController_1 and secondView):
[image]

when I touch Button_1 I add secondView as subview with myTable:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
   {
     [self.view addSubview:secondView];
   }
```

How can I implement that the secondView with table and its methods (DataSource) have been implemented in a separate class? 
Because if I have, for example, 10 buttons??? Then in ViewController_1 will be a lot of code!!!

Comment: Is your secondView uiviewcontroller or uiview?

Comment: It's UIView. If it was ViewController, I can't used addSubview)

Comment: if you have them already in your ViewController_1.xib then there is no effect of addSubview methods coz its already there... aint it?

Comment: Yes, but secondView is not visible until write addSubview:secondView.

Comment: why is it not visible since it is already there? do you mean the secondView is at the lower layer? "its methods (DataSource) have been implemented in a separate class" i dint get this too.

Comment: No, because when I use [self.view setAlpha:0]; I can not see secondView! secondView it's outlet of UIView!

Comment: if i am not mistaken... u have a secondView which is on the same viewcontroller but u r populating the table from another class... when the viewcontroller is loaded the secondView is set to alpha=0, then when the button is clicked the tableview is addSubview... and do you wanna load different data in the table for different button clicked... right?

Comment: hello are want to create grid like table create or not?

Comment: All delegate methods of myTable now in ViewController_1 and I fill it with data from this controller! But!!! If I used 10 or more buttons in ViewController_1 will be a lot of code! Because I need create 10 views in one ViewController_1.xib!!!!

Comment: i think its better to do this way... just use that single view but when you populate the tableView use condition like switch for different cases... and call your-table-view.reloadData every time the button is clicked

Comment: I can't understand how I can separate secondView with table from this class!

Comment: i think the better way is to create different viewcontroller with table in it and when you click the button use  presentModalViewController method to present your second viewcontroller and also pass the data to fill in the table  in the second viewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to take a `SecondViewController` and not view. and when you tap on button then navigate it to that `SecondViewController`. Like as you are saying there are several buttons which in turn leads to hide unhide several other views. then It would be hard for you to manage. And yes there will be lots and lots of coding and flags.

And if at all you like to add view then you can keep the `SecondViewController` as `UIViewController`. Do all the table datasource/delegates methods there and

while adding it to ViewController_1

Try the following code

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
   [self.view addSubview:secondViewController.view];
}
```

Comment: Wow) Thanks!) It's works!) But if I need click on a different buttons and table shows different data? May it implement that the controller was one and table data generation of all of this tables was in this controller? Sorry for my english(((

Comment: Change your array from which you are displaying the data in the table. So when you tap on button_1 you insert few values in array and the table displays that values. Now when you tap on Button_2 you replace the values of the array with teh new values and call [tableview reloadData] method for the updation to take place